# Gmail View Unread In Each Subfolder

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have dozens of subfolders I prioritize to balance my workload, however, in many cases, the unread messages are not listed first.

I would like a simple button on the GUI of Gmail to simply click to view emails that are unread after clicking on each subfolder.

I don't want all unread messages in my inbox. I like to just click on a subfolder I have created and click a button to view all unread messages there only.

This way if I need to I can select all, even if there are hundreds of emails in that specific subfolder which I can mark as read without affecting other unread messages in other folders.

**Examples:**

```
Folder 1 | Server A Down
Folder 2 | Server B Down
Folder 3 | Messages From Boss
Folder 4 | Impacted Services
```

If there are 1,000 services impacted in Folder 4, I would like to just see all the unread ones then mark all as read, then view the details in `Folder 1`.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, all you have to do is add the search label `unread` as follows: `label:unread` to the search area.

When you enter some folder, you'll notice that in the search area of gmail, the term is something like:
`label:toplevelfolder-nextfolder-subfloder-etc`
so just change it to
`label:toplevelfolder-nextfolder-subfloder-etc`**`label:unread`**
and it will do the work :)

If you must have it as a GUI button, maybe there's a browser extension to add that button.